# Swift variable value back to original after loop

Tags: swift, pass-by-value

I have this simple code:

```
for index in 0..<people.count {
    var person = people[index]
    var home = homes[index]
    person.home = home
    println("\(person.home)")
}

for index in 0..<people.count {
   var person = people[index]
   println("\(person.home)")
}
```

Person:

```
struct Person: Deserializable {
    var home: Home?

    init() { }

    init(data: [String : AnyObject]) {
        home <-- data["home"]
    }
}
```

In the `println` statement in first loop, it assigns the `home` to it's respective `person` and prints the proper `home`.

In the second loop, it prints `nil` (back to normal). It's almost as if the first loop has no effect.

I have no idea how to debug this. Please help

Comment: That is your real code? The two loops really come one _right after the other_ in the same function?

Comment: @matt yes, i copy pasted this, i've never seen anything like this... no idea what to do

Comment: Show how person's type is declared.

Comment: @matt updated. and as I updated, I saw the issue :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not give any information about what person *is*. But suppose it is a struct. Then I would not expect there to be any effect on the `people` array's persons, because the person in `var person = people[index]` is a *copy*.

So in that case you would need an extra line in your first loop, writing the altered person back into the array:

```
people[index] = person
```

Comment: You're right. As I was editing my question to show how the Person type is declared, I saw the issue. Thank you.

Comment: yes just did. it didn't allow me before as I had to wait 5 minutes. thanks again for the answer and for AFNetworking!